# How to connect to an Access database that is on a VPS

Tags: database, ms-access, vps

How to connect to an Access database that is on a VPS(Virtual Private Server)

Windows : Windows server 2003

Program language : Delphi or C#

Comment: What is an Access bank and a VPS?

Comment: Access bank = Microsoft Access Database

VPS = Virtual Private Server

Comment: @Tony Toews
program language is not important.

Comment: I think the standard terminology for VPS is actually VPN or Virtual Private Network.

Comment: you mean I shared the DB file and connect by VPN and use the file?

Comment: Ah, so you do mean the definition of VPS as per wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server?  If so my answer below is still the same as a WAN is still involved.

Comment: Yes, the Wiki is true, but your answer didn't help me.
You're right, an Access DB is not good for this job but I have to use it, so it should be a way to use it.

Comment: Access/Jet/ACE files are so heavily tied to the Windows file system that I'd be very wary of any kind of virtualization at all.

Answer (score 1):

An Access database file is not designed to be shared over a WAN (Wide Area Network) which a VPN implies.   You'd be best using a product such as SQL Server or MySQL or similar.

As far as programming language, Delphi or C# they can both, work with Access, SQL Server, MySQL or other ODBC databases.    Your question is very general.